# Parse json string where numbers have commas instead of dots

Tags: javascript

I have a string that I would like to deserialize into a json object.

Unfortunately I do not have control over the content of the string.

Is there a simple way to do this?

`let result = "{\"var1\": 15,000, \"var2\": 22,000, \"var3\": 333,000, \"var4\": 77,000}"`

I have tried:

`JSON.parse(result);`

Comment: Good luck with that, you should complain loudly to whoever sent you that data. It's not valid JSON.

Comment: I know, but I really do not have control over that

Comment: Any attempt you make to try to fix it will be very fragile. For instance, if the JSON data contains a string that contains numbers, it will probably remove the commas there as well.

Comment: Can you ask them how *they* process the data in their own applications? You should be able to copy that.

Comment: You are surely allowed to inform the sender that the JSON output you receive is invalid and point them to www.json.org - numbers with fraction digits must use a `.`.

Comment: I agree with Barmar, there is no proper way of solving this. The only workaround I can think of is to write a RegEx that searches a comma inbetween two digits. But that's obviously not a valid solution. Primarly I too would contact the owners of this API and inform them about their malformed output.

Comment: In your example I don't see any fraction numbers, those commas are thousand separators

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will definitely talk over to the API developers.

Comment: Why not simple `/,(?=\d{3})g/` regex before parsing?